# Adding hashes and files names to lists and dictionaries

Tags: python

Hey guys I was able to get the hashes to individually work for the files I input. I was wondering how to add the file name to the list I have set and the hash to the other dictionary. I feel like it is a pretty simple fix I am just stuck.  we have to use a file path on our machines that has been established already. the folder I am using has 3 or 4 files in it. I am just trying to figure out how to add each of the hases to the lists Thanks!

```
from __future__ import print_function

'''
Week Two Assignment 2 - File Hashing
'''

'''
Complete the script below to do the following:
1) Add your name, date, assignment number to the top of this script
2) Using the os library and the os.walk() method 
   a) Create a list of all files
   b) Create an empty dictionary named fileHashes 
   c) Iterate through the list of files and
      - calculate the md5 hash of each file
      - create a dictionary entry where:
        key   = md5 hash
        value = filepath
    d) Iterate through the dictionary
       - print out each key, value pair
    
3) Submit
   NamingConvention: lastNameFirstInitial_Assignment_.ext
   for example:  hosmerC_WK1_script.py
                 hosmerC_WK1_screenshot.jpg
   A) Screenshot of the results in WingIDE
   B) Your Script
'''

import os
import hashlib
import sys
    
directory = "."

fileList   = []
fileHashes = {}

# Psuedo Constants

SCRIPT_NAME    = "Script: ASSIGNMENT NAME"
SCRIPT_AUTHOR  = "Author: NAME"
SCRIPT_DATE = "Date: 25 January 2021"



print(SCRIPT_NAME)
print(SCRIPT_AUTHOR)
print(SCRIPT_DATE)


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):

    # Walk the path from top to bottom.
    # For each file obtain the filename 
    
    for fileName in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fileName)
        fullPath = os.path.abspath(path)
        
    print(files)
    
''' Determine which version of Python '''
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    PYTHON_2 = True
else:
    PYTHON_2 = False
    
def HashFile(filePath):
    ''' 
        function takes one input a valid filePath
        returns the hexdigest of the file
        or error 
    '''
    try:
        with open(filePath, 'rb') as fileToHash:
            fileContents = fileToHash.read()
            hashObj = hashlib.md5()
            hashObj.update(fileContents)
            digest = hashObj.hexdigest()
            return digest
    except Exception as err:
        return str(err)
        
print()

if PYTHON_2:
    fileName = raw_input("Enter file to hash: ")
else:
    fileName = input("Enter file to hash: ")

hexDigest = HashFile(fileName)
print(hexDigest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've done most of the work in the assignment, so kudos to you for that. You just need to refine a few things and use your functions together.

1. For item **"a) Create a list of all files":** In the `for fileName in files:` loop, add the line `fileList.append(fullPath)`. *(See [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) for more info.)*

   - indent it so it's part of the `for` loop.
   - Btw, the `print(files)` line you have is outside the loop so it will only print the files of the last folder that was `os.walk`'ed.
   - Change that to `print(fileList)`
2. **For "c) Iterate through the list of files and...":**

   - Iterate through the `fileList` and call the `HashFile()` function for each file. The return value is the *key* for your dictionary and the filepath is the value:

     ```py
     for filepath in fileList:
         filehash = HashFile(filepath)
         fileHashes[filehash] = filepath
     ```
   - The one-line version of that, using a dictionary comprehension:

     ```py
     fileHashes = {HashFile(filepath): filepath for filepath in fileList}
     ```
3. For **"d) Iterate through the dictionary":** I think you'll be able to manage that on your own. *(See [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) for more info.)*

Other notes:

A.) In the `except` block for calculating hashes, returning a string of the error - was the pre-written for you in the assignment or did you write it? If you wrote it, consider removing it - coz then that error message becomes the hash of the file since you're returning it. Possibly just print the error; unless you were instructed otherwise.

B.) The "input filename" part is not needed - you'll be calculating the hash of the all files in the "current" directory where your script is executed (as shown above).

C.) Btw, for md5, since finding collisions is a known flaw, may want to add each file as a list of values. Maybe it's part of the test. Or can be safely ignored.

Comment: A. the except was written for us as the starter. and once I get the dictionary set up I should be able to print it, correct?

Comment: and where does that for block go. I am confused

Comment: The fileHashes-dictionary for-loop? That goes at the end of your file, or anywhere after the `fileList-os.walk` loop. Also, don't just "print" the dictionary, with `print(fileHashes)` - use the method I hinted at above, with a loop.

Comment: it is just printing the filePath, its not printing anything further

Comment: `for hash, path in fileHashes.items(): print(hash, path)`. That's all that was left to do, for (d).